# What is the use for format strings in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
formatter = "%{first} %{second} %{third} %{fourth}"

puts formatter % {first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4}

puts formatter % {first: "one", second: "two", third: "three", fourth: "four"}

puts formatter % {first: true, second: false, third: true, fourth: false}

puts formatter % {first: formatter, second: formatter, third: formatter, fourth: formatter}

puts formatter % {
  first: "I had this thing.",
  second: "That you could type up right.",
  third: "But it didn't sing.",
  fourth: "So I said goodnight."
}
```

I am confused for what you would use format strings in ruby, could somebody eexplain to me. Thanks

Comment: Your example doesn't use many of string format's  features, especially converting and padding.  See [here](https://www.blackbytes.info/2012/01/ruby-string-formatting/) for a tutorial on this

Comment: This isn't really a good question. Format strings are very common in languages from back in early Fortran, and are used to provide a means to adjust column widths and alignment of columns in text. Ruby isn't isolated in providing them, so a search of "format strings" will return a number of links describing them and their value. "[ask]" and the linked pages and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudocode:

```
MAIL_TEMPLATE = <<-TMPL
Hello, %{name}!

The support for %{product} will be ended at %{date} unless
due to insufficient amount of money on your account %{account}.

The amount to pay to continue using %{product}: %{debt}
TMPL

Storage.all_users.map(&:to_hash).each |user|
  send_email(user.delete[:email], MAIL_TEMPLATE % user) if user[:debt]
end
```

The above might be used for sending emails to users that have no sufficient amount of money on their accounts. Notice, that there are 2LOC, besides the email template.

Please also refer to very valuable comment by @mu-is-too-short below.

Comment: And importantly, `MAIL_TEMPLATE` is just a string that could be stored in a separate file (which couldn't happen with `#{}` interpolation unless you want to use `eval` or similar unpleasantness).